# Clear previous return data from DataBase in HTML using PHP+JSON+AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I am doing Database project and I built Database and UI, the communication between the DB and the UI is made by PHP,JSON and AJAX.
In the Top 3 tab I am trying to bring the top 3 student with the highest grades, my plan was to use a dropdown options and pick each time another course and bring the top 3 each time. The code is working but not as I wanted.
It is always append the new results to the last results. If I am trying to bring another top 3 student it is append the new results to the last results and not clearing the previous data. [image: Before and after clicking to another results from db.]

My code is :

Javascript:

```
    $('#showCourse').click(function(){
        console.log("showCourse");
        var top3 = $('#top3').val();
        var top3Table = $('#top3Table');
        console.log(top3);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data: {"top3" : top3},
            url: "jsonTop3.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){  
                console.log("success");      
                console.log(data.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var row = "<tr><td>" + data[i].student_id + "</td>" +
                                     "<td>" + data[i].grade + "</td></tr>";
                    top3Table.append(row);
                  }
          }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="insertData" style="height:180px;">
        <h3>Pick Course name:</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <select class="form-control" id="top3" onchange="document.getElementById('text_content').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
                <option>None</option>
                <option>Operational Systems</option>
                <option>Integrators</option>
                <option>Web Development</option>
                <option>Algebra</option>
                <option>Chimestry</option>
                <option>Biology</option>
                <option>History</option>
                <option>JAVA</option>
                <option>Intro to Math</option>
                <option>UNIX</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="hid" id="text_content" value="">
        </form>
                <div class="rightButtons">
                <button type="add" name="type" class="btn btn-success" id="showCourse">Show</button> 
                </div>
        </div>
<div class="table">
    <h2>Top 3 Table</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody id = "top3Table">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    function printStudents() {
      $host="127.0.0.1";
      $port=3306;
      $user="root";
      $password="root";
      $dbname="courcessystem";

     $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reg_courses
        ORDER BY course_id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($con));

        $emparray = array();
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $emparray[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($emparray);
        $con->close();   
    }   

    printStudents();

?>
```

Comment: it appends the results because you use `top3Table.append(row);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
success: function(data){  
      var row = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         row += "<tr><td>" + data[i].student_id + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + data[i].grade + "</td></tr>";
      }
      top3Table.html(row);
   }
```

instead of your success function

Comment: This way it would insert only the last row

Comment: @abidibo thanx ) i fixed my answer and published correct function code

Answer (score 1):

What about empty the table before appending rows?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {"top3" : top3},
        url: "jsonTop3.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){  
            console.log("success");      
            console.log(data.length);
            top3Table.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var row = "<tr><td>" + data[i].student_id + "</td>" +
                                 "<td>" + data[i].grade + "</td></tr>";
                top3Table.append(row);
              }
      }
```